# ElementRef.find() not a function angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

im trying to convert my angular 1 directive code to angular 2. But it throws an error saying ElementRef.find() is not a function. is there any other way to achieve the same. to find element inside an element.

Angular 1

```
link: function ($scope, $elem, attrs) {
            var elem = $elem[0] table = $elem,
                thead = table.find('thead'),
                tbody = table.find('tbody'),
       }
```

Angular 2

```
 constructor(el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {
    this.elem = el.nativeElement;
    this.table = el,
    this.thead = this.table.find('thead');
    this.tbody = this.table.find('tbody');
    this.tableWidth = this.table[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {}

```
 //ngAfterContentInit() { // for directive or projected content
 ngAfterViewInit() { // for searching a components template
    this.elem = el.nativeElement;
    this.table = el,
    this.thead = this.table.querySelector('thead');
    this.tbody = this.table.querySelector('tbody');
    this.tableWidth = this.table[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
 }
```

`find` is `jQuery`. There is no `jQuery` included in Angular2.

See also [angular 2 / typescript : get hold of an element in the template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template/35209681#35209681)

Comment: this.table inside the angular 2 directive docent show the inner elements. so the querrySelector docent work . even tried this.table.nativeElement.querySelector('thead')

Comment: Please provide more code. It's impossible to diagnose what's going on from these tiny code fragments. You also need to move the code from the constructor to `ngAfterViewInit()` if the HTML is in the template of a component, or to `ngAfterContentInit()` if the code is in a directive or if its projected content - updated my answer.

Comment: perfect `this.table.nativeElement.querySelector('thead');` inside  `ngAfterViewInit()`  worked.